# What is the proof that the variance of the gradient estimate in Actor-Critic is smaller than in REINFORCE?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, proofs, actor-critic-methods, reinforce

The intuition provided when introducing actor-critic algorithms is that the variance of its gradient estimates is smaller than in REINFORCE as, e.g., discussed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKqxumCuAAY&feature=youtu.be&t=278). This intuition makes sense for the reasons outlined in the linked lecture.

Is there a paper/lecture providing a formal proof of that claim for any type of actor-critic algorithm (e.g. the Q Actor-Critic)?

Comment: I don't think this is something that can be formally proved, at least not in general. It can be measured in a range of environments, or could be shown more robustly in a specific constructed environment.